# "Not a statement" Compile Error in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am having a problem when I am trying to compile a pattern program. I am creating this program in BLUEJ and when I am trying to compile it  shows the error : "**not a statement**"

```
class pattern
{
    public static void main()
    {
        int p=0;
        for(int i=1;p=1;i<=4;i++,p++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(Math.pow(p,2);

            }
            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: missing parenthesis after Math.pow() -- extra semi-colon in for loop declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of issues there, the main one being this:

```
for(int i=1;p=1;i<=4;i++,p++)
//         ^   ^    ^
```

The `for` statement consists of *three*, not four, parts separated with `;`. I suspect you wanted

```
for(int i=1,p=1;i<=4;i++,p++)
//         ^--- comma here
```

Separately, I believe you have to specify the argument to `main` even if you're not using it, so:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

---

In a comment on the qustion, [cadrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47461/cadrian) pointed out a further problem:

```
System.out.print(Math.pow(p,2);
// Missing ) here ------------^
```